# Instantiate a list inside a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, list, constructor

I'm trying to build a list inside a class in C++ and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
class Car(){  
public:  
    Car();  
    ~Car();  
    list <Objects> myList;  //a list of some objects from one of my classes  
    list <Objects>::iterator it;  
    void addObject(Object obj);  
    void removeObject(Object obj);  
};  

Car::Car(){  
    //what do I need to add to initialize the list
    it = myList.begin();
};  

void addObject(Object obj){  
    //myList.insert(it, obj);  
    myList.push_back(obj);
}  

void removeObject(Object obj){  
    myList.remove(obj);  
}
```

I don't get any build errors, however the debugger shouts at me "Expression: list insert iterator outside range". I believe I'm not initializing the list inside my constructor and that's the reason why. How can I do it?
Thanks

Everything is sorted now with inserting, however I'm having problems removing from the same list.
I presume it has to do with these "lovely" pointers. To get this once and for good, in my main I'm creating an object of type Car. Then I create some objects of type Object. Then I add them to my Car object using the above code. Why can't I remove them? And most important: how many instances of the same object did I create using this code:

```
int main(){  
    Car myCar = Car();  
    Object one = Object("first object");  
    Object two = Object("second object");  
    Car.addObject(one);  
    Car.addObject(two);  
    Car.removeObject(one);  //doesn't work???
}
```

Could someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? Does anything have to do with my passing objects by value? What is the correct way in doing the above?
Thank you.

Comment: As it stands, the code looks OK, but you should make sure you understand the container's iterator invalidation behaviour. The list will be correctly initialized (to an empty list).

Comment: @Kerrek : This will default-initialize a `std::list<>::iterator`, which is not okay.

Comment: @ildjarn: What's the problem? Iterators can be default-initialized. Later on, `it` gets a valid value assigned to it in the constructor body. Not elegant, but functional.

Comment: @Kerrek : Confusion on my part apparently. I was thinking that sentinal iterators for containers were not legal, but in fact they're legal as long as you assign a valid value to them before otherwise using them, which is being done here.

Comment: I was using an iterator to display all the objects stored in the list and I thought to keep the same approach if/when I want to add a new object to a specific place. Why do you say it's not elegant?

Comment: @Adrian: Not initializing the iterator is inelegant. You should learn about constructor initializer lists. Whether your overall use of an iterator class member makes sense is not for me to tell. It's not a very common construction, but you may well have your reasons for it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm just learning now so there are moments when I'm not sure which is the correct way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list will be initialised automatically in your constructor and you don't need an iterator as a class member. To add your object to the list you should just call push_back:

```
void addObject(Object obj){  
myList.push_back(obj);  
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/

To insert at a specific location see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/insert/

If you are going to arbritrarily decide where to insert your new object then you will need to determine where each time using find(), if you were going to always insert at beginning or end then it's easy enough to call

```
// insert in arbitrary location
myList::iterator it = myList.find(val);
myList.insert(it, obj);
// OR insert at beginning
myList.push_front(obj); // to insert at end see above
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP has some reason to track an iterator, too. It's impossible to tell without further information. Perhaps the setup is unusual, but it's not impossible.

Comment: I would only initialise the list if you want to set the minimum or default size or default values for that size, your iterator will be invalidated everytime you add a new element to the list so there is no point keeping track of it unless you want it to always point at the end of the list which is just it = myList.end();. In any case please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was about to give a similar answer when the page wanted an update for this one.  For the TC, I suspect that the debugger thought the `begin` iterator wasn't valid because the list is empty.  But as we said, you didn't need it.  Additionally, your class, once the iterator member is removed, won't need to specify constructors (or a destructor) at all; the default lifetime-management behavior should do the right thing (unless the real code has build-up and/or break-down code that's skipped here to make the example shorter).

Comment: The `push_back(obj)` works like a charm however, later on if I would like to add an object to a specific place, I believe this method it not the recommended one. Thank you.

Comment: Use insert with the iterator pointing to where you want it to either at myList.begin() or myList.end() or you do a find call like iterator it = myList.find(obj); and then call myList.insert(it); The important thing here is that you expect your iterator to be valid after you insert or remove an element from a list because if you think about you could have changed some of the element ordering.

Comment: Some reason I cannot edit my last comment should read: The important thing here is that you cannot expect your iterator to be valid after you insert or remove an element from a list because if you think about it you could have changed some of the element ordering

Answer (score 1):

Your list has been initialized just fine.

The debugger is trying to be helpful and show you the element pointed to by the `it` iterator. Since you haven't added any elements to the list, the list is empty, and `myList.begin()` does not point to a valid element.

Once you add an element to the list, the error message goes away. However, I'm not sure if your `it` iterator automatically becomes valid or if you need to call `myList.begin()` again.

You haven't posted your `Object` class definition, but removal probably doesn't work because your `Object` class doesn't implement `operator==` properly. Nothing to do with pointers (unless `Object` uses pointers inside) or passing by value.

Declaring your methods as `void addObject(Object obj)` instead of `void addObject(const Object& obj)` does mean that for every call you'll create an extra instance of `Object`.

Comment: what do you mean by "class doesn't implement `operator==` properly"? Think of the Object class exactly as the Car class without any methods. I'm not sure I understand where to use `==` in that class and what for. Thank you

Comment: @Adrian, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677913/remove-elements-with-specific-value-from-stdlist

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see here is that you may be using list.end() somewhere that you're not showing here.  Remember, list.end() actually points past the end of the list and not at the actual last member of the list.  To append to the list, it is better to use 'push_back'.